# Testing order of lines of text on web page - Rspec & Capybara in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, capybara

Maybe I am missing the obvious...

I can easily test for the presence or absence of text on a web page.

Is there a straightforward way to test for the order of items listed in a div or on a web page, say from top to bottom?

So, if I am expecting

1. This
2. That
3. The other thing
4. And one more item

... to be displayed in that order.  Is there a matcher or test method that can be invoked to check the web page content?  It should fail if something like this were displayed:

1. This
2. The other thing
3. That
4. And one more item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order of display is the same as in the html, for example:

```
<div id="one">This</div>
<div id="two">That</div>
<div id="three">The other thing</div>
<div id="four">And one more item</div>
```

Then it should be possible like this:

```
it "should have the right order" do
    elements = all('#one, #two, #three, #four'); # all in one selector
    expect(elements[0]['id']).to eql('one');
    expect(elements[1]['id']).to eql('two');
    expect(elements[2]['id']).to eql('three');
    expect(elements[3]['id']).to eql('four');
end
```

The order of elements should be the same like they appear in the document. Tested it by myself.

Answer (score 6):

You could do it with CSS or XPath selectors:

```
expect(page.find('li:nth-child(1)')).to have_content 'This'
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Also see:
http://makandracards.com/makandra/9465-do-not-use-find-on-capybara-nodes-from-an-array

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this using RSpec Matchers/Index

```
  def items_in_order
    page.body.index('This').should < page.body.index('That') &&
        page.body.index('That').should < page.body.index('The other thing') && 
            page.body.index('The other thing').should < page.body.index('And one more item')
  end
```

Comment: the page.body.index doesn't seem to work inside a within() block

Answer (score 0):

As a variant:

```
 expect(some_el).to have_text(/This .+ That .+ The other thing .+ And one more item/)
```